# Unable to get previous loaded URL in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get the previous URL in my login page using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], it shows undefined index.

I need to get the referrer URL in domain.com/login, it will redirected from domain.com/subfolder/logout. the logout page redirect to my login page, but I couldn't get the referer URL as the logout URL.

I tried `window.history.go(-2);` and `window.history.go(-1)`; , it only redirects to empty page not print any value.

Comment: REFERER is an optional field, the browser / client is not required to send it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notice: Undefined index: HTTP\_REFERER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976189/notice-undefined-index-http-referer)

Comment: With the two previous comments it might be a better idea to save the previous URL in a session variable. That should be easy enough to access. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: @MichaelRennison not able to get the previous URL to save, that is my issue. is this because of the main domain and subdomain redirection?

Comment: If the user browsed to the login URL by writing it directly in the address bar, there is no referer...

Answer (score 0):

it is showing undefined index HTTP_REFERER because when you will be landing first time of page else it will working you can test it like below:

create `test.php`

```
<a href="http://localhost/test1.php">asdf</a>
<?php

print $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

create `test1.php`

```
<a href="http://localhost/test.php">asdf</a>
<?php

print $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

output:

```
http://localhost/test.php    // => on http://localhost/test1.php
```

```
http://localhost/test1.php    // => on http://localhost/test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my answer in this post. Use sessions to save your current location and then use to if you want to go back.

[Redirect User to the page they've left off once they had log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628661/redirect-user-to-the-page-theyve-left-off-once-they-had-log-in/60630357#60630357)

Answer (score -1):

you can use $_SESSION[] for your pages .